# How to insert a timestamp in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have some attribute is date time on this format "2017-06-23 15:34:48".can  and I set that to NSDate. But the value is not inserting on the table can anyone help me 
I added this object as NSDate

```
2017-06-23 15:34:48 I want to insert on this format.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135267/nsdateformatter-with-24-hour-times

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:@"2017-06-23 15:34:48"];
NSLog(@"%@", myDate);
```