# iPhone 6 and 6 plus date format @"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" does not work unless system date is set to 24 hours in the Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

On my iPhone 6 and 6 plus, the date format `@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` does not work unless system date is set to 24 hours in the Settings.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
dateFormater.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

NSString *dateString = @"2017-06-12T22:20:04+05:30";
dateFormater.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDate * startDate = [dateFormater dateFromString:[dateString substringToIndex:19]];
```

I am getting `nil` as start date.

Comment: Go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135267/nsdateformatter-with-24-hour-times . You have to set the local to  [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];

Comment: You need to use HH as your time is in 24 hour format

Comment: `YYYY` is wrong anyway. It's for ISO 8601 week based calendars. Standard year is `yyyy`

Comment: @iOSDev please **do not** format non-code like this: `iPhone 6` and `6 plus`. The backticks are meant for code only, not for emphasis. (Not sure why you want to emphasize those anyway, but...)

Comment: @Glorfindel Noted, Thanks for inform.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**For 12 Hrs**

```
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"];
```

**For 24 Hrs:**

```
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically mention the local 
dateFormater.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
or otherwise ,in iPhone 6 and 6 plus with iOS version 10.3.2 the conversion of NSString to NSDate will not be give nil value for NSDate. When different local is selected in phone settings.

NSDate * startDate = [dateFormater dateFromString:[dateString substringToIndex:19]];

Answer (score 0):

Its not issue of any particular device. Your dateformater component is wrong.

hh -> This is used for 12 hours formate.
HH -> This is used for 24 hours formate.

Here is brief description about all of them, so you can get idea:

a: AM/PM

A: 0~86399999 (Millisecond of Day)

c/cc: 1~7 (Day of Week)

ccc: Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat

cccc: Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday/Saturday

d: 1~31 (0 padded Day of Month)

D: 1~366 (0 padded Day of Year)

e: 1~7 (0 padded Day of Week)

E~EEE: Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat

EEEE: Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday/Saturday

F: 1~5 (0 padded Week of Month, first day of week = Monday)

g: Julian Day Number (number of days since 4713 BC January 1)

G~GGG: BC/AD (Era Designator Abbreviated)

GGGG: Before Christ/Anno Domini

h: 1~12 (0 padded Hour (12hr))

H: 0~23 (0 padded Hour (24hr))

k: 1~24 (0 padded Hour (24hr)

K: 0~11 (0 padded Hour (12hr))

L/LL: 1~12 (0 padded Month)

LLL: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec

LLLL: January/February/March/April/May/June/July/August/September/October/November/December

m: 0~59 (0 padded Minute)

M/MM: 1~12 (0 padded Month)

MMM: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec

MMMM: January/February/March/April/May/June/July/August/September/October/November/December

q/qq: 1~4 (0 padded Quarter)

qqq: Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4

qqqq: 1st quarter/2nd quarter/3rd quarter/4th quarter

Q/QQ: 1~4 (0 padded Quarter)

QQQ: Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4

QQQQ: 1st quarter/2nd quarter/3rd quarter/4th quarter

s: 0~59 (0 padded Second)

S: (rounded Sub-Second)

u: (0 padded Year)

v~vvv: (General GMT Timezone Abbreviation)

vvvv: (General GMT Timezone Name)

w: 1~53 (0 padded Week of Year, 1st day of week = Sunday, NB: 1st week of year starts from the last Sunday of last year)

W: 1~5 (0 padded Week of Month, 1st day of week = Sunday)

y/yyyy: (Full Year)

yy/yyy: (2 Digits Year)

Y/YYYY: (Full Year, starting from the Sunday of the 1st week of year)

YY/YYY: (2 Digits Year, starting from the Sunday of the 1st week of year)

z~zzz: (Specific GMT Timezone Abbreviation)

zzzz: (Specific GMT Timezone Name)

Z: +0000 (RFC 822 Timezone)

Comment: I am trying to covert the date string to NSDate.
this is my date string @"2017-06-12T22:20:04+05:30";
Now if I set the date formatter local as [NSLocale currentLocale];
It is unable to render the NSDate object for the date formatter [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

This issue occurs only in iPhone 6 and 6 plus when from settings 24-hours Time is switched off.

This issue is not happening in 6s or 7.